# invalid literal for int() in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

When I run a code below, there is an error. Why does this happen? I can get a value from `{{ ssh.port }}` or `{{ ssh.port|int }}` and when I replace `{{ ssh.port|int }}` with `10022`, it works.

```
$ ansible-playbook -i staging site.yml
```

> ERROR! Unexpected Exception: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
>   '{{ssh.port|int}}'

```
# staging
[webservers]
IP_ADDRESS

[all:vars]                                                                                                                                            
env=staging

# site.yml
- include: webservers.yml

# webservers.yml
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: deploy
  port: "{{ssh.port|int}}"
  become: True
  gather_facts: False
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/credentials/{{ env }}
  roles:                                                                                                                                              
    - common

# group_vars/all.yml
ssh:
  port: 10022
```

Ansible: 2.1.0.0, Mac: 10.11.5

Comment: It works when I ran the code using Ansible1.9.6. So did I the wrong way or is this a bug on Ansible >= 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible bug. Error occurs [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/playbook/play_context.py#L242).
Play attributes are not yet templated here and int() throws error.

But I'd advice you to use `ansible_port: 10022` variable in your `group_vars/all.yml` file to achieve what you want. 
This will automatically set ssh port to this value.

Or you may patch the `play_context.py` to remove int() – this will work, but I don't know the possible drawbacks.

Comment: Thank you for your information! But I want to change ssh port like below, so I don't want to use `ansible_port` in `group_vars/all.yml`..
`- hosts: webservers port: 22, - hosts: webservers port: 10022`